# SQL project monthly rent obligation on lease

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a report that returns the monthly rent due broken down by year.  Currently we only go out six years, but would like the report to calculate to `N` number of years.

This is the way I currently have the report set up

```
SELECT endDate
    ,term
    ,rentDue
    ,YEAR(endDate) AS yearLeaseEnds
    ,DATEDIFF(MONTH, @Date, endDate) AS totalMonthsRemaining --Count of months remaining in lease.
    ,(12 - MONTH(@Date)) AS monthRemainYear --number of months remaining this year.
    ,CASE 
        WHEN YEAR(@Date) = YEAR(endDate) THEN DATEDIFF(month, @Date, endDate) * rentDue --For leases ending the same year as the date selected
        ELSE (12 - MONTH(@Date)) * rentDue --For leases that do not end the same year as the date selected.
     END AS 'CurrentYear' 
    ,CASE   
        WHEN YEAR(@Date) + 1 > YEAR(endDate) THEN 0 --exclude leases that ended prior year.
        WHEN YEAR(@Date) + 1 = YEAR(endDate) THEN MONTH(endDate) * rentDue --When the end date is current year calculate the rent due for that year.
        ELSE 12 * rentDue
     END AS 'YearOne'
    ,CASE   
        WHEN YEAR(@Date) + 2 > YEAR(endDate) THEN 0 --exclude leases that ended prior year.
        WHEN YEAR(@Date) + 2 = YEAR(endDate) THEN MONTH(endDate) * rentDue --When the end date is current year calculate the rent due for that year.
        ELSE 12 * rentDue
     END AS 'YearTwo'

     ... -- add CASE statements for each projected year

FROM leases
```

As you can see I have to add a CASE statement for each year I want to project rent due for.  I tried doing a WHILE loop but I'm not well versed in SQL loops.

```
DECLARE @i AS INT;  --loop counter
DECLARE @n AS INT;  --years to project
DECLARE @Date DATE;  --date to project rent obligations as of.

SET @Date = '2014-06-30' 
SET @i = 0
SET @n = 5

WHILE @i <= @n
BEGIN
    SELECT CASE 
        WHEN YEAR(@Date) + @i > YEAR(endDate) THEN 0 --exclude leases that ended prior year.
        WHEN YEAR(@Date) + @i = YEAR(endDate) THEN MONTH(endDate) * monrent --When the end date is current year calculate the rent due for that year.
        ELSE 12 * monrent --when the end date is in the future calculate the entire year's rent obligation.
     END AS RentDue
FROM leases
SET @i = @i + 1
END;
```

;

Is there a way to return each result of the loop as columns?

Perhaps do a recursive method?  But how do I create the recursion so it is not infinite.

**Edit**: sample data and expected results.

sample

```
LeaseID |   endDate    | rentDue    
--------+--------------+--------    
1       |   2014-10-31 |    50          
2       |   2015-03-31 |    25          
3       |   2016-12-17 |    6000        
4       |   2017-11-01 |    300
```

expected result

```
LeaseID     endDate     rentDue     ... CurrentYear YearOne YearTwo ... years to N
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           2014-10-31  50          ... 200         0       0       ...
2           2015-03-31  25          ... 150         75      0       ...
3           2016-12-17  6000        ... 36000       72000   72000   ...
4           2017-11-01  300         ... 1800        3600    3600    ...
```

Comment: Increment the @i in your loop add after BEGIN, `SET @i=@i+1`,you also need an END for BEGIN.

Comment: @Mihai - yes, seems that I missed copying that part of the loop.  I've updated it though. thank you

Comment: can u post sample data and expected output,...

Comment: @Anand sample and expected output added.

Comment: I suggest you use a tally table instead of a loop, (which will give you a row per year) and make your report software pivot those rows into columns. I will give more information if you're interested.

Comment: @ElectricLlama Sure, please.  I was actually reading up on using pivot and unpivot and wondering how it may work with SSRS.

Comment: The best idea is to get your reporting tool to send the data unpivoted to SSRS (one record per year), then get SSRS to pivot it. That way you don't need to have dynamic columns in your SQL. This is almost always the best approach - let the reporting tool pivot it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to use a sub query to return all of the fields you are after from leases with an extra year out calculation, then do your calculations based on the years out in the other query and filter all by a max years out parameter.

```
DECLARE @YearsOut INT
DECLARE @Date DATETIME

SET @Date='01/01/2012'
SET @YearsOut=6

SELECT  
     CASE   
        WHEN YEAR(@Date) + YearsOut > YEAR(endDate) THEN 0 --exclude leases that ended prior year.
        WHEN YEAR(@Date) + YearsOut = YEAR(endDate) THEN MONTH(endDate) * rentDue --When the end date is current year calculate the rent due for that year.
        ELSE 12 * monrent --when the end date is in the future calculate the entire year's rent obligation.
     END AS RentDue
     ,YearsOut 
FROM
(
    SELECT  *
        ,YearsOut=DATEDIFF(YEAR,@Date,endDate)      
    FROM
        leases
)AS X
WHERE 
    YearsOut BETWEEN 0 AND @YearsOut
```

The same can be accomplished with the following query, but notice that instead of comparing the INT value YearsOut everytime you evaluate the condition you will be running a DATEDIFF() function.

```
DECLARE @YearsOut INT
DECLARE @Date DATETIME

    SET @Date='01/01/2012'
    SET @YearsOut=6

    SELECT  
         CASE   
            WHEN YEAR(@Date) + DATEDIFF(YEAR,@Date,endDate) > YEAR(endDate) THEN 0 --exclude leases that ended prior year.
            WHEN YEAR(@Date) + DATEDIFF(YEAR,@Date,endDate) = YEAR(endDate) THEN MONTH(endDate) * rentDue --When the end date is current year calculate the rent due for that year.
            ELSE 12 * monrent --when the end date is in the future calculate the entire year's rent obligation.
         END AS RentDue
    FROM
       leases
    WHERE 
        DATEDIFF(YEAR,@Date,endDate) BETWEEN 0 AND @YearsOut
```

One other small point. For any value that uses a function repetitively you can save a few calculations by either running the function once in the subquery or calculating the value as a constant parameter prior to the query...

```
DECLARE @YearsOut INT
DECLARE @StartYear INT
DECLARE @Date DATETIME
DECLARE @EndYear DATETIME    

SET @Date='01/01/2012'
SET @YearsOut=6

SET @StartYear=YEAR(@Date)
SET @EndYear=YEAR(@Date) + @YearsOut

SELECT  
        CASE   
        WHEN YearsOutCalc > endYear THEN 0 --exclude leases that ended prior year.
        WHEN YearsOutCalc = endYear THEN endMonth * rentDue --When the end date is current year calculate the rent due for that year.
        ELSE 12 * monrent --when the end date is in the future calculate the entire year's rent obligation.
        END AS RentDue
FROM
(
    SELECT  *
        ,endYear=YEAR(endDate)
        ,endMonth=MONTH(endDate)
        ,YearsOutCalc=DATEDIFF(YEAR,@Date,endDate) + @StartYear     
    FROM
        leases
)AS X
WHERE 
    YearsOutCalc BETWEEN @StartYear AND @EndYear
```

As for showing one year per year ahead...you do not need to return these columns in your query. Instead use column a column group that is grouped by your leaseID. That will push your years ahead out by the maximum years ahead specified in your dataset.

```
RowGroupLeaseID Header-----            |<--ColumnGroupYearsOut 
    LeaseID     endDate     rentDue    | <Fields!YearsOutLabel.Value>
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RowGroupLeaseID Detail-----            |
    <LeaseID>   <ednDate>   <rentDue>  |  <Fields!YearsOutValue.Value>
```

This will give you something similar to:

```
LeaseID     endDate     rentDue     ... CurrentYear YearOne YearTwo ... years to N
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           2014-10-31  50          ... 200         0       0       ...
2           2015-03-31  25          ... 150         75      0       ...
3           2016-12-17  6000        ... 36000       72000   72000   ...
4           2017-11-01  300         ... 1800        3600    3600    ...
```

Comment: This is useful, especially the last piece as this will eventually have two parameters to select and start/end dates to gather data, thank you.  However my struggle is turning those `yearsOut` into columns.  Suppose a lease has 5 years left and I ask to give me that 5 year projection.  I want a column for each calendar year.  `YearOneRent`, `YearTwoRent` ... `YearFiveRent`.

Comment: For your second part take a look into Column Groupings in ssrs where you can push values out by year number. On the sql side of things a Pivot command is useful. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=SQL.105).aspx